# Dowload a Copy of a folder to computer Sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010

I'm attempting to download an entire folder from a sharepoint 2010 site. I have all the administrator permissions one could want and can alter settings as I please. However, I can't seem to figure out how to get the "Download a Copy" button to be enabled for multiple files or folders as shown in the screenshot below.

[image: Sharepoint 2010 Folder selected Download a Copy]

My question is: How do I enable the "Download a Copy" button for single folders, multiple folders, and multiple files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, **this is not possible to download a folder, or multiples files, with SharePoint 2010**. That's why the button is disabled. Only SharePoint Online with modern experience allows this scenario for a few years.

The only workaround is to develop a custom solution (custom action to add a button, C# code with an ASP.NET handler to process the request, compress the folder or files, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work on 2010 but I've done this on 2013:
-Try clicking on the Library Tab in the Ribbon.
-Then see if there is an "Open With Explorer" option.
-If that's greyed out, open in Edge.
-If it's still greyed out, click on the 3 ellipse (the 3 dots at the upper right corner), then click on "Reload in Internet Explorer".
-- After Edge reloads in IE mode, then try clicking on the Library Tab, Open with Explorer, and see if File Explorer Opens.
-- If so, then you should see a File Explorer version of your SharePoint site with the folders.
-- Then you can copy and paste in another folder on your desktop.
-- Be advised, sometimes copy and paste may not work because of long document library names or multiple sub libraries along with long file names.
-- Also, be sure to close the File Explorer when finished.